# How to create texture for stained plastic?

Tags: roughness

You can see the white spot under Sony Text. I think Spot reflection and randomize on black plastic surface. sometime used headphone, ps3 and other electronic plastic material.
I've been searching texture like this for a long time. So far, I don't know exactly how to do it. How to call exactly? Some people used to voronoi texture to get this result but for me it didn't work. How can I do it... thank everyone.

[image: Stained plastic]

Comment: Try to looks specifically for "texture/material imperfections" or "surface imperfections" You should find a lot of materials for creating this. Personally, I make things like that procedurally with Voronoi texture + colorRamp to create them. But if you need textures there are tons of them to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the speckles are a variation in the reflectivity of the particles in the composite. They show up more brightly in the highlights, and, to some extent, are darker in the shadows. They should 'sparkle' slightly? Different flecks should be picked up according to view/light angle?

You could use a fine *Voronoi*.

[image]

1. Use it to vary the base color between black and dark grey
2. Select a fraction of the cells with a *Greater Than* threshold, and reduce their roughness, for glint and piano-black..
3. Use it to introduce a very slight height-variation for a *Bump* node

[image]

You can cheat the 'Specular' fraction in the BSDF a bit?

If the flecks are too obviously Voronoi cells, you could muddle them slightly by mixing with *Noise*

Comment: Thank You Very Much ! This is exactly what I want. I'm really appreciate for your kindness answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with a *Noise Texture* and a *ColorRamp*, and add a bit of bump:

[image]